# Android TV Receiver App cannot launch according to the config in my cast console

Tags: android, chromecast

I install the demo app "com.google.sample.cast.castconnect" on an Android TV
It is from Android Cast code lab

When I connected to cast through Android Demo sender app.
The receiver app is launch

So, I implement my cast sender and add "com.google.sample.cast.castconnect" into my cast console

However, the demo receiver app doesn't launch. The web receiver launched

Is there anything wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same problem.